# Fill Dash-core-component dropdown with a choice based on a button press

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have a bunch of buttons on my page, dynamically generated, and would like to fill in a dropdown with the appropriate account matching the button.
My dropdown is setup like this in layout

```
dcc.Dropdown(id='spread-order-buy-account',
             options=[{'label': k, 'value': k.lower()} for k in ACCOUNT_CHOICES])
```

and

```
dcc.Dropdown(id='spread-order-sell-account',
             options=[{'label': k, 'value': k.lower()} for k in ACCOUNT_CHOICES])
```

and my callback is set up like

```
@app.callback([Output('spread-order-buy-account', 'value'),
          Output('spread-order-sell-account', 'value')],
          Input({'type': 'symbol-button', 'index': ALL}, 'n_clicks'),
          State('global-spreader-investor', 'active_tab'),
          prevent_initial_callback=True)
def fill_accounts(*args):
    states = dash.callback_context.triggered
    if len(states) and states[0]['value']:
        clickedElement = json.loads(states[0]['prop_id'].rsplit(".",1)[0])['index']
        if (isinstance(clickedElement, str)):
            theRow = df[df['symbol'] == clickedElement]
            buy_account, sell_account = choose_best_accounts(theRow, args[1])
            return buy_account, sell_account
    return dash.no_update
```

Where the input `symbol-button` can be any one of many, which are all associated with a buy and sell account, retrieved appropriately in `choose_best_accounts(theRow, investor)`.

I've confirmed that the function gets to the return line with `buy_account` and `sell_account` matching choices that are currently populated in the dropdowns, but they don't show up when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

The value was originally set as `k.lower()`. `buy_account` and `sell_account` need to be returned with `.lower()` as well